# Button is always null when trying to find it?

Tags: kotlin

I have this code:

```
    val btn_click_me = findViewById(R.id.button1) as? Button
    btn_click_me?.setOnClickListener {
        // do something
    }
```

which gives me this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.widget.Button` even though it exists in my layout file

the button is always null. how can i fix ? how can I set on click listener to button?

doing this from fragment...

Comment: where are you trying to do this activity or fragment?!

Comment: @HenriqueVasconcellos fragment

Comment: Please, provide more context. It's not clear where you're creating and setting your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need context to find your ViewById. I recommend doing with *requireContext()* like this

```
    val btn_click_me = requireContext().findViewById(R.id.button1) as? Button
    btn_click_me?.setOnClickListener {
        // do something
    }
```

Also, if you wanna look into other ways of doing this, I recommend looking for [viewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)